# QML plugin cannot be loaded for module %modulename%: Failed to extract plugin meta data from %module.so%

Tags: qml, qt5

I wanted to write QML plugin to expose some classes from Qt to QML layer. I followed the guide from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html). Here is the code:

**expose.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += qt plugin
QT += qml gui

DISTFILES += expose.json
DESTDIR = ../g/Expose
TARGET = expose
SOURCES += expose.cpp
```

**expose.cpp**

```
#include <QQmlExtensionPlugin>
#include <QQmlEngine>

#include <QGuiApplication>

class QGuiApplicationWrapper : public QGuiApplication {
    int argc;
public:
    QGuiApplicationWrapper() : QGuiApplication(argc, nullptr) {}
};

class QExampleQmlPlugin : public QQmlExtensionPlugin {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID QQmlExtensionInterface_iid)
public:
    void registerTypes(const char *uri) {
        Q_ASSERT(uri == QLatin1String("g.Expose"));
        qmlRegisterType<QGuiApplicationWrapper>(uri, 1, 0, "GuiApplication");
    }
};
```

But when I try to `import g.Expose 1.0` from QML, the following error appears:

`plugin cannot be loaded for module "g.Expose": Failed to extract plugin meta data from 'g/Expose/libexpose.so`

I looked into the code of the loader (**qlibrary.cpp**):

```
bool ret = false;

if (pos >= 0) {
    if (hasMetaData) {
        const char *data = filedata + pos;
        QJsonDocument doc = QLibraryPrivate::fromRawMetaData(data);
        lib->metaData = doc.object();
        if (qt_debug_component())
            qWarning("Found metadata in lib %s, metadata=\n%s\n",
                     library.toLocal8Bit().constData(), doc.toJson().constData());
        ret = !doc.isNull();
    }
}

if (!ret && lib)
    lib->errorString = QLibrary::tr("Failed to extract plugin meta data from '%1'").arg(library);
```

So I guess some json must be provided and specified in in `Q_PLUGIN_METADATA` but I cannot find a place in documentation which describes its format and inclusion procedure

Comment: That's odd. [The documentation for `Q_PLUGIN_METADATA`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtplugin.html#Q_PLUGIN_METADATA) says "FILE is optional and points to a json file.", so you shouldn't have to provide it.

Comment: @Mitch I think it is optional in the sense that you can use the Qt plugin mechanism for your own application specific plugins and if you don't need any meta data you don't have to provide any.
It could be required for specific plugin aware subsystems such as QML

Comment: @Grief Not related to the problem but your code: I am not sure you can instantiate a Qt application object from QML, it is likely already required at the point before the QML engine is created. What is your goal here?